# Displaying related content UNDER the CURRENT li in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a repeated list repeating category names from my JSON data. Each `li` is it's own repeated list of people related to that category (see [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/bEXXOy)) What I want to do is open a div under the current nested `li` displaying data regarding the individual clicked. My demo has it working except it opens under EACH `li` instead of the current one. I know there is probably a solution similar to the `select(i)` i have in the demo but can't quite get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

**My HMTL:**

```
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="starWarsCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cat in getCategories()">
          <h2>{{cat}}</h2>
          <div ng-click="select(i)" ng-repeat="i in data | filter:{cat: cat}">
    <p>{{i.name}}</p>
  </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**My AngularJS:**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])

.controller('starWarsCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    {"name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi",
     "index":88,
      "cat": "jedi"},
    {"name": "Yoda",
     "index":69,
      "cat":"jedi"},
    {"name": "Lando",
     "index":31,
      "cat": "smuggler"},
    {"name": "Han Solo",
     "index":90,
      "cat": "smuggler"},
    {"name": "Darth Vader",
     "index":98,
      "cat": "sith"},
    {"name": "Jar-Jar Binks",
     "index":80,
      "cat": "alien"},
    {"name": "Mace Windu",
     "index":45,
      "cat": "jedi"},
    {"name": "Chewy",
     "index":76,
      "cat": "smuggler"}
  ];

   $scope.select = function (item) {
    $scope.selectedItem = item;
  }

  $scope.getCategories = function() {
    var categories = [];

     angular.forEach($scope.data, function(item) {
    //item.cat is a string
    if (categories.indexOf(item.cat) == -1) {
      categories.push(item.cat);
    }
});
    return categories;
  }

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer is adding

```
&& cat === selectedItem.cat
```

to your `data-ng-if`. This checks whether the cat & selectedItem are matching appropriately.